# Using the Stored Procedure's Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have MyStoredProcedure that returns 1 if OK and 0 if NOK.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure 
AS
RETURN 1
GO
```

the following code does not work :

```
IF MyStoredProcedure() = 0 --GOTO END, do something
```

(I call MyStoredProcedure from another SQL procedure)

How can I use this return value?

SQL Server 2005

Comment: Which DBMS is this - MS SQL Server?

Comment: err.... from what language are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: I call the procedure from another SQL procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use EXEC command in SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

for example

```
DECLARE @ret int;
EXECUTE @ret = MyStoredProcedure;

IF (@ret = 0)

...
```

Comment: can I write this in one single line? I have multiple procedure calls like this... `IF XXX = 0 --END_PROC, IF YYY = 0 --END_PROC`

Comment: @serhio - No, but it sounds like you might need some re-factoring there.

Comment: Oh, yeah! I know there is a lot o refactoring in this old database, anway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it like this by name, you need to define it not as a stored procedure, but as a Scalar UDF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx#S1

Then you can use function name in your other code.

Comment: Then define an output parameter in `MyStoredProcedure()` assign it to a variable and use it in the condition